# Why Multithreading is not working perfectly in AWS Lambda function?

Tags: java, multithreading, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless

```
public class LambdaFunctionHandler implements RequestHandler<Object, String> {

    @Override
    public String handleRequest(Object input, Context context) {
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("Hello");
            }
        }
    Thread thread1 = new Thread(runnable);
    thread1.start();
    Thread thread2 = new Thread(runnable);
    thread2.start();
    Thread thread3 = new Thread(runnable);
    thread3.start();
    Thread thread4 = new Thread(runnable);
    thread4.start();

    }}
```

I've tried normally and it works fine. but on the lambda function it will not work properly.
    Thread is dying before the complete excution of threads. when return statement called it is automatically stopping threads.

```
Expected result
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello


Actual Result 

Hello
```

Comment: Looks like you did not join the threads

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java thread start not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43764665/java-thread-start-not-working)

Comment: @smac89 how can i do that ?

Comment: There is a `;` missing. Beside that the code within the method gives the expected result.

Comment: Look at the duplicate question. The answer is there

Comment: I'm facing issue in only AWS lambda , Normally it is working fine

Comment: There is no thread join needed

Comment: @Meini i've forget to place it but issue is not regarding compiling

Comment: Well the point of @smac89 is that you print to console before the thread is started  but this is not possible since you print to console in the thread itself. I guess there has to be an influence on it which cannot be detected just by this code snippet.

Comment: See this thread: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=828475&tstart=0

Comment: creating two lambda function is not good way i think @smac89

Comment: From what I've been reading on AWS lambdas, it seems it is not helpful to spawn threads inside the lambda function. You are better off dispatching the work to multiple lambda functions or doing it synchronously. Also no-one seems to be talking about joining threads, so I think that may just be a feature of the lambda functions

Comment: right @smac89 i think lambda function can not fulfill my requiremnt

Answer (score 5):

As people said in the comments, the problem is that you are not waiting for the threads to complete. You return from `handleRequest()` as soon as you're done starting threads. This tells Lambda that your execution is done, so it suspends your container before those threads have a chance to execute.

"Suspends your container" is the difference between running on Lambda and running locally. When you run locally the JVM actually exits, and it won't do so until all non-daemon threads have finished.

To ensure that all threads run, you need to call explicitly join them before returning from your handler function.

To help you understand how this works, you should also add some more debugging information (use `System.err` because it's unbuffered):

```
@Override
public String handleRequest(Object input, Context context) {

    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.err.println("Hello from " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        }
    };

    Thread thread1 = new Thread(runnable);
    thread1.start();
    Thread thread2 = new Thread(runnable);
    thread2.start();
    Thread thread3 = new Thread(runnable);
    thread3.start();
    Thread thread4 = new Thread(runnable);
    thread4.start();

    thread1.join();
    thread2.join();
    thread3.join();
    thread4.join();

    System.err.println("handler function exiting");
}}
```